# System of Non-Linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Does anyone have any clue of how to find an analytical solution for the following system:

$$
\frac{dF_1}{dt}=(p+qF_1-rF_2)(1-F_1)
$$
$$
\frac{dF_2}{dt}=vF_1(1-F_2)
$$

$p$, $q$, $r$ and $v$ are constants. $F_1(0)=F_2(0)=0$.

Comment: I have a pretty strong suspition an analytical solution for this won't be composed of elementary functions.

Comment: It would be great if I could find out in what conditions I have $dF_1/dt < 0$. I'm thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

here is my attempt at a solution:
split the system of two equations with the eqaution for $F_1$ decoupled from $F_2$ as 
$$\frac{dF_1}{dt} = \frac{1-F_1}{F_1}\mbox{ and }\frac{dF_2}{dt} = \frac{\nu(1-F_2)}{p+qF_1 - rF_2}.$$

we can solve $-F_1 + \ln(1-F_1) = t$ for $F_1.$ too bad no explicit solution for $F_1.$

i will see if can go any farther with this.

Comment: How did you decouple $F_2$ from the first equation?

Comment: you can rewrite your autonomous system as $\frac{dF_1}{dF_2} = \frac{(p+qF_1-rF_2)(1-F_1)}{\nu F_1(1-F_2)}.$  now split this as i did. we could do this because the right hand side of your equations did not depend on time explicitly(autonomous).

Comment: Nice. I'll try something with this approach. Thanks!